# warnings::warnif( 'deprecated' ... ) with carp?

Tags: perl

I would like to send a deprecation notice like

```
warnings::warnif( 'deprecated', 'function foo is deprecated' );
```

but I'd prefer to have it carp up so it reports to the caller and not where the actual warn is. Can I do this with `carp` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [tried it?](http://ideone.com/vSnCJz)

```
package Foo {
    sub bar {
        warnings::warnif(deprecated => 'Foo:bar is deprecated');
    }
}

use warnings;
# no warnings 'deprecated';    # <-- uncomment this to disable the warning
Foo::bar();                    # <-- this is line 9
```

This should say something like:

```
Foo::bar is deprecated at test.pl line 9.
```

In fact, looking at the [warnings.pm source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/lib/warnings.pm), it seems to use Carp.pm internally.  Admittedly, the documentation for the warnings pragma itself could be clearer about this, but [perllexwarn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#Reporting-Warnings-from-a-Module) does make it pretty clear that this is how it's meant to be used.

Comment: yes I tried it.. the MOP is throwing off all my line numbers... apparently even now that I've set `@CARP_NOT` appropriately, so I didn't realize it was doing the right thing (or originally that `@CARP_NOT` would be getting obeyed ). now I guess I need to figure out what I'm missing since I put `__PACKAGE__` in `@CARP_NOT` but it still appears to be carping from package and not the test file.