# Carp reporting from the wrong location with @CARP_NOT (Moose and Method Modifiers)

Tags: perl, moose, carp

This is a followup question to [warnings::warnif( 'deprecated' … ) with carp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993724/206466).

here's a snippet of my code from [Business::CyberSource on Github](https://github.com/xenoterracide/Business-CyberSource/blob/3574165f56d904d123090c7b23fc257ad6e49b3d/lib/Business/CyberSource/Client.pm#L29-L40)

note: the previous answer (in the previous question), and adding of `@CARP_NOT` have demonstrated that `warnings::warnif` uses `carp`. I attempted to substitute carp directly, the behavior was exactly the same.

```
our @CARP_NOT = ( __PACKAGE__, qw( Class::MOP::Method::Wrapped ) );

around BUILDARGS => sub {
  my $orig  = shift;
  my $class = shift;

  my $args = $class->$orig( @_ );

  if ( exists $args->{username} ) {
    warnings::warnif('deprecated',
        '`username` is deprecated, use `user` instead'
    );
```

But when I [call this code](https://github.com/xenoterracide/Business-CyberSource/blob/3574165f56d904d123090c7b23fc257ad6e49b3d/t/new-client.t#L8-L13)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

use Business::CyberSource::Client;
my $class = 'Business::CyberSource::Client';

my $client
= new_ok( $class => [{
    username   => $ENV{PERL_BUSINESS_CYBERSOURCE_USERNAME} || 'test',
    password   => $ENV{PERL_BUSINESS_CYBERSOURCE_PASSWORD} || 'test',
    production => 0,
}]);
```

The error is still reported from the wrong place (though at least not from `Class::MOP::Method::Wrapped`)

```
t/new-client.t .. `username` is deprecated, use `user` instead at constructor Business::CyberSource::Client::new (defined at /home/xenoterracide/Documents/Business-CyberSource/lib/Business/CyberSource/Client.pm line 314) line 6.
```

How can I make this report from the correct line number in the test file? (note: behavior did not change if I called `->new` directly instead of using `new_ok`

Comment: so you want it reports the line number of `new-client.t` or `Client.pm`?

Comment: it should be reporting the line number in `new-client.t` because that's the caller.